# LinearLayout hide once when uncheck the first checkbox of customize ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i saw this question [android how to hide linearlayout when no checkbox is checked in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469590/android-how-to-hide-linearlayout-when-no-checkbox-is-checked-in-listview)
i have listview with checkbox in each row, i want when there is at least one checkbox is selected a linearylayout (contains two buttons) to be visible and when no checkbox is selected i want that lineylayout to hide,

i made exactly like that question but it works just with the first checkbox, i mean when i check the firstcheckbox it work, then if i uncheck the linearlayout hide but if i check another checkbox the linearlayout still visible all the time
adapter

```
public class AdapterFavoriteFoods extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> cb_status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    Activity activity;
    LinearLayout ll_CancelDone;
    private int checkedBoxs = 0;
    CheckBox[] allCheckBoxes;

    public AdapterFavoriteFoods(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, LinearLayout ll_CancelDone) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.ll_CancelDone = ll_CancelDone;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            cb_status.add(false);
        }
        allCheckBoxes = new CheckBox[data.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_item_checkbox, null);
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_list_item_checkbox_title);
        ImageView iv_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_list_item_checkbos_image);
        CheckBox cb_selected = (CheckBox) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.cb_profile_list_item_checkbox_checkbox);
        allCheckBoxes[position] = cb_selected;
        cb_selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    cb_status.set(position, true);
                    checkedBoxs++;
                    if (ll_CancelDone.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    cb_status.set(position, false);
                    checkedBoxs--;
                    if (checkedBoxs == 0)
                        ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        cb_selected.setChecked(cb_status.get(position));

        HashMap<String, String> hm = data.get(position);
        tv_name.setText(hm.get("name"));
        iv_image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(hm.get("image")));
        return vi;
    }
}


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469590/android-how-to-hide-linearlayout-when-no-checkbox-is-checked-in-listview
```

when i do this `Log.d("num", checkedBoxs+"");` in the else statemnt of oncheckchange the results still 1 ,

Comment: Please don't add `android` to the question's title, the android tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you should keep the state, most important don't keep references to the row `CheckBoxes`. Try this:

```
//...
CheckBox cb_selected = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.cb_profile_list_item_checkbox_checkbox);
cb_selected.setChecked(cb_status.get(position));
cb_selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
          cb_status.set(position, isChecked);
          boolean status = false;
          for (Boolean b : cb_status) {
               if (b) {
                   status = true;
                   break;   
               }
          }  
          ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(status ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
     }
});
```

Comment: why u remove the counter ? in your code where i know how many checkboses are selected ? also what is the last statment do ?

Comment: @tottiroma If you're going to show the `LinearLayout` whenever there is at least a `CheckBox` selected in one of the rows then you don't need the counter. Have you tested my code?

Comment: your code made the linearlayout hide just when it is check then uncheck by the same checkbox

Comment: your code made the linearylayout hide just when it is checked by checkbox then unchecked by another checkbox

Comment: when i put the `cb_selected.setChecked(cb_status.get(position));` out of the oncheckchanged it works

Comment: @tottiroma The code is simple. Whenever a `CheckBox` is checked in one of the rows in the `OnCheckedChangeListener` you'll first set the new status in the `cb_status` list. Then you'll traverse the `cb_status` list and see if we have a value of `true` in it. If we found a true value then there is at least one `CheckBox` checked and we show the `LinearLayout`. If all the values are false, then we hide the `LinearLayout` because no `CheckBox` is checked at that moment.